# Any way to know the group by clause in aggregation formula

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In an in house business intelligence system, I have to provide some KPI which 
I struggle on to deliver one
This one has a different way to be calculated according to the aggregation level

> Ex: I have a hierarchy
>
> > level1/level2/level3

All of the members have some custom weight and I have to calculate weighted average, so the value if I do a group by

> level1,level2 is
>
> > sum(value * level3weight) / sum(level3weight)

if I do a group by level1 only I have to do the previous calculation first at level2 and then use that result to do

> sum( the result of my previous calculation,level2weight)/sum(level2weight)

All of that is easy to do if I can do some custom query with sql subqueries,
the problem is the in house "BI system" that generate simple sql and I have to provide views.
This sql generator can only generate `min/max/sum/avg`
I try to find a way to write in the aggregation: "if I have level2 in the group by clause, then I will do this formula, otherwise, i will do another formula".

I tried to use grouping() but if I test level2 and level 2 is not in the group by list, the query crash.

If I had SSAS i will have used MDX SCOPE operator, I don t know if there is an equivalent to MDX SCOPE in SQL.
I also cannot use CLR custom aggregation.

The only solution I see now is to provide 2 views with 2 indicators (one for level 1 and 1 for level 2) but this will not work as I have multiple levels and multiple hierarchies to manage.

If anyone has an idea

Thanks

Comment: Please share the data schema and your query so far. An example of the output you would like to get will help as well.

Comment: I would urge you to read this question and ask yourself if you would be able to answer this based only what you posted. At this point it isn't even clear what your are asking for help with. It is a wall of text with no clarity as to what you want.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.